# How to write sitemap file with XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, sitemap, xmlwriter

I am trying to automate my generation of site map.

I am trying to generate this xml output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I have

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"books.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("urlset");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.Flush();
}
```

it renders this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset`

it seems to have problems with `xmlns` if I remove this, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartelement?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlWriter_WriteStartElement_System_String_System_String_ of `WriteStartElement` e.g.

```
string ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
```

and then

```
writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", ns);
writer.WriteStartElement("url", ns);
```

and so on.